# Backend Rest Api testing using Protractor

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

Where can I find examples of end to end testing with Backend Rest Api testing included using protractor and jasmine?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *"Backend Rest Api testing"* here; end to end testing would *include* the site touching any API endpoints, or do you mean testing the REST API more directly? Either way SO isn't here to find things for you

Comment: directly  to test REST API  with basic  Authentication using protractor

Comment: Why? That's really not what it's designed for; it's a browser driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "http" module available in nodeJs to make http request and then process the response recieved from the api call. Look at the below example

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
   host: 'example.com',
   port: 80,
   path: '/foo.html'
};

http.get(options, function(resp){
   resp.on('data', function(chunk){
   //do something with chunk
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
   console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "http" or "request" module to make the calls to the server.
I recommend that the api calls return a promise so in the tests you can use the browser.wait() function and wait for the call to be fulfilled

```
let apiCall = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(url, function (error, response, json) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
               return resolve(JSON.parse(json));
            } else {
                return reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And in your tests

```
it("validates something",()=>{
 //...
  browser.wait(apiCall(),timeout).then(json => {
              //do stuff with json
            });
 // Continue with your test
}
```